# Twig(Symfony2) - new lines

Tags: symfony, twig, newline

I have a problem with twig templates. I would like to create a template with some text and keep the new lines character but when it renders the new lines are gone!

This is what I have in my template:

```html
John 
Doe
```

Output:

```html
John Doe
```

What I would like to get:

```html
John
Doe
```

How can I do this ? Please help.

Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the filter `|nl2br` which transforms new lines to `<br>` and also the `|raw` filter, so HTML tags are interpreted if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Use `<pre>` marks:

```
<pre>John
Doe</pre>
```

Will output

```
John
Doe
```

Comment: Not really. It will output it with <pre> tags and I want a clean text so I could paste it in the textarea.